# How to find location of JDK crossplatform

Tags: java

How would I find the location of the JDK on a device even with different platforms. Would I have to search through the files brute force? If so, that seems like it would get a little tough because it could be located in several different folder branches.

Comment: *"How would I find the location of the JDK on a device(?)"*  1) JDK or JRE? 2) Why?  What feature does this help you to provide to the user?

Answer (score 0):

[`System.getProperty("java.home")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) will return the installation directory of the JRE. From there you could look up the file tree to see if this is the JDK's JRE, or to see if the JDK is in nearby parent folder.

Comment: @StephenC `Installation directory for Java Runtime Environment (JRE)` Read the link on my answer, it is correct. `user.home` returns the user's home directory.